# How to create random monsters

Tags: java, swing

I am making a game like Space Impact. In my game the rockets are working correctly, but I can't create monsters randomly. Monsters are on the screen but they aren't moving so they aren't active 
How can I do this?

```
public class Dnm extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    Graphics dbg;
    Image dbImage;
    Image Pik1;
    Image Boss;
    static ImageIcon active;

    int x, y, xDirection, yDirection, BossX, BossY;

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                move();
                boss();
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Uh-oh, something went wrong!.");
        }
    }

    private void move() {
        x += xDirection;
        y += yDirection;
    }

    private void boss() {
        while (BossX == 0) {
            BossX = getX() - 1;
        }

        Random rastgele = new Random(getY());
        BossY = rastgele.nextInt();
    }

    public void setXDirection(int xdir) {
        xDirection = xdir;
    }

    public void setYDirection(int ydir) {
        yDirection = ydir;
    }

    // KEY COMMANDS //
    public class AL extends KeyAdapter {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

            if (keyCode == e.VK_LEFT) {
                setXDirection(-1);
            }
            if (keyCode == e.VK_RIGHT) {
                setXDirection(+1);
            }
            if (keyCode == e.VK_UP) {
                setYDirection(-1);
            }
            if (keyCode == e.VK_DOWN) {
                setYDirection(+1);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            if (keyCode == e.VK_LEFT) {
                setXDirection(0);
            }
            if (keyCode == e.VK_RIGHT) {
                setXDirection(0);
            }
            if (keyCode == e.VK_UP) {
                setYDirection(0);
            }
            if (keyCode == e.VK_DOWN) {
                setYDirection(0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    }

    // CONSTRUCTOR //
    public Dnm() {
        //Image Import
        ImageIcon still = new ImageIcon("img/rocket.png");
        Pik1 = still.getImage();

        addKeyListener(new AL());

        setTitle("Dnm");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(true);
        setVisible(true);

        x = 15;
        y = 15;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        paintComponent(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("img/space.jpeg");
        Image background1 = background.getImage();

        ImageIcon still1 = new ImageIcon("img/Alien.png");
        Boss = still1.getImage();

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawImage(background1, 0, 0, this);
        g.drawImage(Boss, BossX, BossY, this);
        g.drawImage(Pik1, x, y, this);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);

        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dnm game = new Dnm();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(game);
        t1.start();
    }
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: I think this is a perfect opportunity to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Use a RMG -- Random Monster Generator.

Comment: Try to ask your question carefully rather than just copy pasting code. As is there is no way to tell what image is a monster, player or rocket.

Answer (score 1):

With your code being incomplete, it is hard to say for sure, but this line looks suspicious:

```
while (BossX == 0) {
   BossX = getX() - 1;
}
```

This code is mostly likely going to be executed once, right? If BossX is initially zero, the code executes where you change its value. On the next update, BossX is not zero (presumably), so the code doesn't execute. Since BossX is the X coordinate where you are drawing the boss, then it will not move. Instead it just gets redrawn over and over in the same spot.

To get the monster to move randomly, increment or decrement both the X and Y coordinate values randomly during each game loop. Add a second random variable to cause them to move at random speeds in the random direction (by adjusting the coordinate value by a value greater than one).

As NPE commented, you should step through the code in a debugger and find out precisely what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly a beginner at programming, but here is my best attempt:

I would create a method that is called every x seconds that generates a random number using Math.Random().  I would say

```
int number = .5;  
if(number > Math.Random())
     GenerateMonster();
```

Your GenerateMonster method would then create a new object with the default values for monster.  In order for the monster's created to act a certain way, you need to inherit those functions wherever you defined how you want the monster to act.  I don't see the code for these functions so I am assuming you just didn't list them.  Hope this at least helps.  Good Luck!